# Connect bulk in diode-connected transistor in synchronous rectifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, rectifier, cmos

The diode-connected transistor is used for synchronous rectifier. I have just drawn bulk diode as below.
The fist one is mosfet with its bulk-source, bulk-drain diodes.
Second and third pictures are when B-S or B-D are connected together.
When B-D is tied together, we have body effect and this increases threshold voltage. However, we get a diode from D to S. I think this diode is good because it helps make the diode-connected transistor more like a real diode.

With the case B-S connected, we don't suffer from body effect but we don't have the help of diode from D to S.

So, my question is which one is better in this case, connect bulk with source or drain?

[image]

Comment: With BD connected diode becomes conducting with Nch positive drain, so no good

Comment: That is not what we want? We want D and S conducts when D is more positive than S.

Comment: Do you want Diode to conduct below Vgs threshold? When Vgs is greater than threshold, FET shunts diode. Reverse protection is preferred use.

Comment: To make it a real switch, I want it to conduct when Vgs > 0, so no voltage drop across the switch.

Comment: Then use sub-threshold <1V MOSFET

Comment: "To make it a real switch, I want it to conduct when Vgs > 0". So you want a switch that has no voltage drop, and doesn't need any bias voltage to turn it on?

Comment: Yes, that is ideal case. However, what I see from the configuration where B and D are connected, there is a benefit. It is something like two diodes in parallel. One formed by MOS and the other is body diode. For that reason, the voltage drop across it may be smaller.